# Induced map in model categories

Tags: category-theory, direct-sum, model-categories, cofibrations

In the snippet below I do not understand what is $$X_i\to X_i \coprod_{L_i X}L_i Y ,$$
i.e. how is it defined and why is it a cofibration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morphism $X_i\to X_i\coprod_{L_iX}L_iY$ is just the lower map of the pushout square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
L_iX @>>> L_iY \\
@VVV @VVV \\
X_i @>>> X_i\coprod_{L_iX}L_iY
\end{CD}

Since $L_iX\to L_iY$ is a cofibration, so is its pushout along $L_iX\to X_i$ (as cofibrations are preserved by pushout); i.e., $X_i\to X_i\coprod_{L_iX}L_iY$ is a cofibration.

Comment: Ok. Where can I find the fact that cofibrations are preserved by pushouts in Hovey's book ?

Comment: And yet,of which two cofibrations is the map in the snippet $$X_i\to Y_i$$ composition of ?

Comment: It's probably more helpful for you to work it out yourself: anything defined by a left lifting property will be preserved by pushouts, and cofibrations are precisely those morphisms with the left lifting property against trivial fibrations. Set up a lifting problem for the pushout morphism and see if you can find a lift (hint: use the universal property of a pushout)

Comment: as for your second comment, $X_i\to X_i\coprod_{L_iX}L_iY\to Y_i$ is the composite you're looking for

Comment: And why is the second arrow in your comment above a cofibration ? I now know why the first one is a cofibration.

Comment: check the definition of $f:X\to Y$ being a cofibration

Comment: I have read the definition of cofibrations on Hovey's book 1.1.3 on page 3, but I still do not know how it follows that that second $\to$ is a cofibration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112159/discussion-between-shibai-and-user122424).